# PHP: MySQL table structure

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, html-table

I'm developing a website that has some audio courses, each course can have multiple lessons.
I want to display each course in its own table containing its different lessons.

What kind of a database should I make?

Example as a static website:

```
<p><span class="heading1">Course 1 - Speaker 1</span> </p>
    <p><span class="date">Posted in <a href="Audio.html">TAG 1</a>, december 12, 2010</span></p> 
    <class id="text">
    <p>Info: blablabla</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <table  border: none cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1">
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">Nr.</th>
        <th scope="col">Lesson</th>
        <th scope="col">Date </th>
        <th scope="col">Download</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td scope="row">1</td>
        <td>blablabla</td>
        <td>22/12/2010</td>
        <td><a href="">MP3</a></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td bgcolor="#D6D6D6" scope="row">2</td>
        <td>blablabla</td>
        <td>22/12/2010</td>
        <td><a href="">MP3</a></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

Course 2 - Speaker 2

```
    <p><span class="date">Posted in <a href="audio.html">TAG 2</a>, december 12, 2010</span></p> 
    <class id="text">
    <p>Info: blablabla</p>
    <table  border: none cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1">
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">Nr.</th>
        <th scope="col">Lesson</th>
        <th scope="col">Date</th>
        <th scope="col">Download</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td scope="row">1</td>
        <td>blablabla</td>
        <td>06/12/2010</td>
        <td><a href="01.mp3">MP3</a></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td scope="row">2</td>
        <td>blablabla</td>
        <td>13/12/2010</td>
        <td><a href="02.mp3">MP3</a></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Table: courses**
id
title

**Table: lessons**
id
cid  *(course id)*
title
date
file

**Sample SQL:**

```
SELECT
    lessons.*,
    courses.title AS course
FROM
    lessons
INNER JOIN
    courses
        ON
    courses.id = lessons.cid
GROUP BY
    lessons.id
ORDER BY
    lessons.date
```

I figure you could easily just use an auto-incrementing variable for the lesson number, as you output the table. However, if there are actually specific lesson numbers, you may want to add it as a field to the database.

You may also want to add additional order by arguments.

Comment: Aren't lessons unique to courses? If so, rather than having a cross-reference table, you should simply have a `lessons.course_id` field.

Comment: Ya know, I didn't think enough about it.  You're right.  Edited my answer to reflect it.

Comment: Thanks! Another question: What kind of a table structure do I need if I wanted to expand it with different Speakers and tags. And being able to sort by Course, Speaker or Tag.